# Genetic Algorithm as global planner plugin

Tags: ros, base-global-planner, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on project "path planning for differential drive". Now I try to write genetic algorithm planner plugin based on "iPath" code. My code in this repository : https://github.com/huyrua291996/ga_planner.git
But it do not work, it can not create the plugin.
The results here:

```
... logging to /home/huy/.ros/log/effd1a2c-4d34-11e9-a995-acd1b8d84627/roslaunch-huy-Inspiron-3543-10660.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319338/genetic-algorithm-as-global-planner-plugin/) by [huyrua291996](https://answers.ros.org/users/40514/huyrua291996/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-03-25**:
So that crash doesn't really tell you much, it means that in trying to use your plugin that it crashes. You'll need to produce more printouts to find where in the process it fails or use a debugger

**Comment by [huyrua291996](https://answers.ros.org/users/40514/huyrua291996/) on 2019-03-25**:
yes, it means that cant go to my plugin. So do I need more printouts in my plugin or something?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-03-25**:
Yes, you should or use a debugger.

**Comment by [huyrua291996](https://answers.ros.org/users/40514/huyrua291996/) on 2019-03-25**:
And can you help me to check my Cmakelists and my GA_ROS.cpp?

**Comment by [huyrua291996](https://answers.ros.org/users/40514/huyrua291996/) on 2019-03-27**:
Hi @stevemacenski, after I use gdb debugger, I got segmentations error:

```
Thread 1 "move_base" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffdc85bf7c in GA_planner::GAPlanner::initialize(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS*) () from /home/huy/plan_ws/devel/lib//libga_planner_lib.so
```

I cant understand how it happen.
Here is my code:
(header file) https://paste.ofcode.org/vRQg5TcFEwSdwHC7CtUvwx
(source file) https://paste.ofcode.org/YeHnyA8RvcGc9tnxrBbv2C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

user found his mistake in his initialization method!

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0